# MVC dropdownlist select text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Can anyone help with this problem, how can I display the selected option based on the text not the value.

I have tried numerous ways, but cannot seem to get it to work, the closest I got displayed the text, but the value was empty.

`<option value="">Spain  Euro</option>`

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.DisplayCurrenciesTo, Model.DisplayCurrenciesTo,Model.DisplayCurrenciesTo.First(c =>c.Text == "Spain  Euro").Text)
```

also tried

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CurrencyFromId, new SelectList(Model.DisplayCurrenciesFrom, "Value", "Text", Model.DisplayCurrenciesFrom.First(c => c.Text == "Spain Euro").Text))

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CurrencyFromId, new SelectList(Model.DisplayCurrenciesFrom, "Value", "Text", Model.DisplayCurrenciesFrom.First(c => c.Text == "Spain Euro").Selected))
```

Above is just a few of the ways I have tried.

below is what I'm trying to do

```
<option selected="selected" value="Eur">Spain Euro</option>
```

I do not want to use jquery for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CurrencyFromId, new SelectList(Model.DisplayCurrenciesFrom, "Value", "Text", Model.DisplayCurrenciesFrom.First(c => c.Text == "Spain Euro").Value))
```

Editing the answer:

Are you by any chance returning an object from your controller that has an empty value for the property CurrencyFromId? When DropdownListFor is used, any value in the model object will override the value that you specify in the selectlist.

Comment: Hi JKan that is one of the other options I tried, but did not work